# Is there any OnTimeSetUp attribute which accepts parameters in NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a unit testing project that contains all tests for all of my platforms. But depending on platform type I need to make checks in test cases. For example if I have something like this:

```
[TestCase]
public void Do_Sth_ExpectSth()
{
    //Arrange
    //....
    //Act
    //....
    //Assert
    if(TestPlatform.IsMainLine)
    {
        Assert.That(...); //assert something based on MainLine platform
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.That(.....); // assert something else for non mainline platforms
    }
}
```

I could test for each platforms by passing PlatformType enum in `TestCase(...)` attribute but at some point I thought to configure the platform type only once globally and run every test in the project for each platform type.

So, I could have something like this:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class GlobalSetup
{
    [OneTimeSetUp(PlatformType.MainLine)]
    [OneTimeSetUp(PlatformType.Other)]
    public void Configure(PlatformType platform) 
    {
        TestPlatform.SetPlatform(platform);
        //other stuff
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void Reset() 
    {
        //reset
    }
}
```

This would help me because each unit test would run under a specific platform type but in the main time I would not have to change the code for each platform type and re-run again the test project(*which I dont like*). So, I was thinking if there is a `OneTimeSetUp` kind of attribute which will accept params and then every test method is re-run again for different params. I would prefer this rather than setting `PlatformType` in each test method because I make some automapper configuration globally which is based on platform type.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest using inheritance to solve this - with each of the two inheriting classes calling the base class and providing the `platform` value.

Answer (score 1):

`OneTimeSetUpAttribute` only has a default constructor, so it's not possible to pass an argument. In addition, it's not possible to mark the same method twice as a one-time setup method. It is possible to use the attribute twice, on two different methods, but in that case both of them are called for the same fixture.

An alternative approach would be to supply arguments to the `SetUpFixtureAttribute`. That's not available but would be consistent with how NUnit handles `TestFixtureAttribute`. Hypothetically, NUnit could create the `SetUpFixture` multiple times with the argument stored (someplace?) and accessed by the fixtures under it, which would also be created multiple times. That's a significant feature to add to NUnit, but you could request it.

Without such a feature, the best you can do is to use the same arguments to each `TestFixture` that needs them...

```
[TestFixture(PlatformType.Mainline)]
[TestFixture(PlatformType.Other)]
public class MyTestFixture
{
    private PlatformType _platform;

    public MyTestFixture(PlatformType platform)
    {
        _platform = platform;
    }

    ...
}
```

If you don't want to duplicate this in every class, you could use a base class for the tests that run on multiple platforms, placing the attributes on the base. Unless you have a great many such classes, my own tendency would be to duplicate the attributes because that makes it easier for people reading the code to understand what's going on.